# No Country when Searching the country in facebook marketing Api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i've tried to fetch the country that facebook provided for the marketing api in the adset.

in the past 2 days i'believe that i've got the country data. but today i am not get the data for the country

this is the code for doing that

```
        $result = TargetingSearch::search(TargetingSearchTypes::GEOLOCATION, null, $country, ['location_types' => ['country', 'region', 'country_group']]);
```

if i try use another location like region or city like i define above it returning the city and the region

is there anything wrong with my code? or is there any change between the api

i am using PHP SDK 2.8 thanks

Comment: For things that worked, and no longer work, you should report a bug. You can do this here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs
I tried this code, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: i don't know why but when i change my account to my personal account it's working, but when i change it back to my sandbox account it's not working anymore

Comment: that's strange. File a bug for sure!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970042/facebook-marketing-api-geographic-search