# Facebook Marketing API. Geographic search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to get list of all cities of a country from Facebook.

I started from FB documentation of v2.9 here:
[Facebook Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search/v2.9)

And tried of getting list of cities as described using curl:

```
curl -G \
  -d 'location_types=["city"]' \
  -d 'type=adgeolocation' \
  -d 'q=dub' \
  -d 'access_token=<MY_TOKEN>' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/search
```

But it returns empty json. If i remove q=dub parameter it still returns empty data. But if i put country as a type of location, then it nicely returns country list. What am i doing wrong?

It would be also appriciated if you could point how to make it return cities for certain country. There is country_code parameter, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: same here, I can get a list of countries, but empty response for cities

Comment: okay , a little update , I see that even the business manager ui can't find or match the cities for my sandbox account but it does works for real facebook account, not sure why, but yet no response through api even with real account

Comment: Okay done, works for real accounts

Answer (score 0):

Little weird but I was trying this for last few hours and it turns out the search for city is not available when you are using access token that is of a Sandbox account.

I tried the same api endpoints with real facebook advert account's access token and it works.

as of how this works, here is a bit of code that might help future readers :

```
//Include Facebook SDK classes
//use FacebookAds\Api;
//use FacebookAds\ApiRequest;
//use FacebookAds\Object\TargetingSearch;
//use FacebookAds\Object\Search\TargetingSearchTypes;

function searcher() {
    $fbutils = new FacebookUtils(16);
    $account_id = $fbutils->getAccountID();
    $accessToken = $fbutils->getAccessToken($account_id);
    Api::init(fb_app_id, fb_app_secret, $accessToken);
        $result = TargetingSearch::search(
            TargetingSearchTypes::GEOLOCATION, null, 'dub', array(
            'location_types' => array('city'),
    ));
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => fb_app_id,
        'app_secret' => fb_app_secret,
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
        'default_access_token' => $accessToken
    ]);
    $fb = $result;
        $objects = $result->getArrayCopy();
        $objects_arr = array();
    do {
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            $objects_arr[] = $object->getData();
        }
    } while ($objects = $fb->next($objects));

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($objects_arr);
    exit;
}
```

Note : replace constants and variables with your data and this should work for searching cities and use pagination and print result as a pretty array.